# Xamarin Forms: Background Task Limitations in iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I want to download and store the download data in my SQL DB while the app is in the background.

While the app is in the foreground, this process usually takes 45-50 seconds.
It TAKES AROUND 7-8 SECONDS for API's to return the json and then around 30-40 seconds to parse the data and insert into various tables.

I am using, NSURLSession to do the API calls, but after the API's have been called and all the JSON responses have been received, IF i send the APP to the background, the insertion process in the DB stops midway after 30 seconds.... and resumes on its own when the app is brought back to Foreground.

WHAT is the time limit of such background executions?

```
public class iOSLongTaskRunningClass
{
    nint _taskId;
    CancellationTokenSource cts;
    public async Task Start()
    {
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _taskId = UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginBackgroundTask("LongRunningTask", OnExpiration);
        try
        {
            var counter = new TaskCounter();
            await counter.RunCounter(cts.Token);
        }
        catch(OperationCanceledException)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            if(cts.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {

                    MessagingCenter.Send<object>(this, "StopTask");
                });
            }
        }

        UIApplication.SharedApplication.EndBackgroundTask(_taskId);

    }

    void OnExpiration()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Background STOPPED "+ DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Background time remaining: " + UIApplication.SharedApplication.BackgroundTimeRemaining);

        cts.Cancel();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        cts.Cancel();
    }

}
```

}

IN the APPDELEGATE:

```
 [Export("applicationDidEnterBackground:")]
    public override void DidEnterBackground(UIApplication application)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Background ENtered " + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString());

    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: iOS places strict limits on how long a background task can run, and if the EndBackgroundTask call is not made within the allotted time, the application will be terminated. By keeping track of the remaining backgrounding time, and using expiration handlers when necessary, we can avoid iOS terminating the application. For more details, you can refer to [iOS Backgrounding with Tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/ios-backgrounding-with-tasks).